# How to use Java JMS with MQseries

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am trying to develop a JMS **standalone application** to read and write  to a Queue on MQSeries.
My boss asked me to use **pure java JMS** (not ibm.mq lib) to do that.

Here is the information that need to make the jms connection:

```
  mq.hostname=10.10.10.10
  mq.channel=API.CLIENTCHL
  mq.queueManager=MQPETAPI
  mq.port=1422
```

Do you know how to do that Or do you have any link that teach me to do that.

Comment: Do your code run inside of WebSphere Application Server and then connects to WebSphere MQ for messaging, or is your application stand alone and wants to connect to WebSphere MQ for messaging?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The issue here is the requirement that "My boss asked me to use pure java JMS (not ibm.mq lib) to do that."  JMS is a specification and each implementation must comply with the API and the semantics, but is free to do whatever they want at a low level.  It is always necessary to use the implementation classes provided by the transport vendor.  Therefore if you use WebSphere MQ as the transport, you will need to use the IBM MQ JMS classes to write a JMS application.

That said, if you stick with pure JMS API calls you would be able to plug in any transport vendor's classes.  This is what is usually intended when you are given requirements such as that mentioned in the original post.

There's an article describing exactly what you are looking to do called *[Running a standalone Java application on WebSphere MQ V6.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0610_woolf/0610_woolf.html)*  It uses only the JMS API and it uses JNDI in a local file system (a .bindings file).  By swapping out the IBM JMS classes for another vendor and using their JNDI tools you would be able to plug in any JMS transport without changing your code using this approach.

If you want to do the same thing without JNDI, look at the sample programs provided with the MQ client install where you obtained your Java classes.  In a UNIX/Linux system these are in `/opt/mqm/samp` and on Windows they are in `install_dir/tools/jms/samples`. The `SimpleRequestor.java` sample has the following code for initializing your connection factory without JNDI:

```
try {
  // Create a connection factory
  JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
  JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

  // Set the properties
  cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "localhost");
  cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, 1414);
  cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN");
  cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
  cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "QM1");
```

Because this approach does not use JNDI, you are required to write code that is not transportable across transport vendors.  It is IBM WebSphere MQ specific.

If you grabbed the MQ jars from somewhere and do not have the full install (and thus do not have the samples) you can download it as [SupportPac MQC7](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24019253&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en).  The download is free.  In general you should use the latest client, even with a back-level queue manager.  Obviously you do not get V7 functionality from a V6 QMgr but the JMS implementation in the V7 client is much improved, even for V6 functionality.  If for some reason you really must use the V6 client, you can download it as [SupportPacMQC6](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24009961&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en).  Whichever client version you use, make sure to use the corresponding Infocenter.

[V6 Infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp)
[V7 Infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp)

Finally, the landing page with an index for all the SupportPacs is [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg27007197#1).

Comment: "Therefore if you use WebSphere MQ as the transport, you will need to use the IBM MQ JMS classes to write a JMS application." I believe that is only true if you are working directly with MQ. If you are abstracted via a container such as WebSphere Application Server, you can actually write "pure JMS" code as the app container takes care of you working with MQ same as if you worked with the SIBus implementation. All you have to do is make sure your MQ Queues are defined as JMS "Queues" and that you have a QueueConnectionFactory (interfaceing with as if it was a ConnectionFactory).

Comment: This is an interesting semantic dance.  The transport provider's JMS classes *are* in the CLASSPATH one way or another. In your example, the JEE server provides a container within which the IBM MQ JMS libraries are accessed. But either way, the application is still using those specific classes *and can access their vendor-specific methods*. It is not as though the JEE server somehow hides the vendor implementation from the app so it seems a meaningless distinction to me. Also, OP specified a stand-alone JMS app so presumably there's no JEE container in his scenario anyway.

Comment: Thanks all of you spending time to my question. Especially to T.Rob

Answer (score 13):

> **A complete (synchronous) standalone JMS application with TextMessage.**
>   It is IBM WebSphere MQ specific.

```
import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueReceiver;
import javax.jms.QueueSender;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import com.ibm.mq.jms.JMSC;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory;

public class JMSApplicationStandAlone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            /*MQ Configuration*/
            MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName("localhost");
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel("MQ.CHANNEL");//communications link
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(1416);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager("QUEUE.MGR");//service provider 
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);

            /*Create Connection */
            QueueConnection queueConnection = mqQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
            queueConnection.start();

            /*Create session */
            QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            /*Create response queue */
            Queue queue = queueSession.createQueue("QUEUE.RESPONSE");


            /*Create text message */
            TextMessage textMessage = queueSession.createTextMessage("put some message here");
            textMessage.setJMSReplyTo(queue);
            textMessage.setJMSType("mcd://xmlns");//message type
            textMessage.setJMSExpiration(2*1000);//message expiration
            textMessage.setJMSDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT); //message delivery mode either persistent or non-persistemnt

            /*Create sender queue */
            QueueSender queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queueSession.createQueue("QUEUE.REQEST"));
            queueSender.setTimeToLive(2*1000);
            queueSender.send(textMessage);

            /*After sending a message we get message id */
            System.out.println("after sending a message we get message id "+ textMessage.getJMSMessageID());
            String jmsCorrelationID = " JMSCorrelationID = '" + textMessage.getJMSMessageID() + "'";


            /*Within the session we have to create queue reciver */
            QueueReceiver queueReceiver = queueSession.createReceiver(queue,jmsCorrelationID);


            /*Receive the message from*/
            Message message = queueReceiver.receive(60*1000);
            String responseMsg = ((TextMessage) message).getText();

            queueSender.close();
            queueReceiver.close();
            queueSession.close();
            queueConnection.close();


        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Replace the configuration values

Comment: Thanks. This helped me when i was trying out a piece of code connecting to IBM MQ.

Comment: @Premraj , can you please share your jms/mq/ibm dependencies ( ie : pom.xml, lib )

Answer (score 9):

If you don't mind writing WMQ-specific code then you can do

```
MQConnectionFactory cf = new MQConnectionFactory();
cf.setHostName(HOSTNAME);
cf.setPort(PORT);
cf.setChannel(CHANNEL);
cf.setQueueManager(QMNAME);
cf.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
```

then usual JMS resources

```
Connection c = cf.createConnection();
Session s = c.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Queue q = s.createQueue("myQueue"); // replace with real queue name
MessageProducer p = s.createProducer(q);
```

and finally create and send a message

```
Message m = s.createTextMessage("Hello, World!);
p.send(m);
```

(i've typed that in off the top of my head so can't rule out a typo, but it's fundamentally correct). If you're really supposed to be using 'pure JMS' - i.e. with no provider-specific objects - then you need to bind a MQConnectionFactory object in JNDI (take a look at the JMSAdmin tool, it's in the docs) then look it up from your application, i.e.

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(); // or as appropraite
ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory)ic.lookup("myMQfactory"); // replace with JNDI name
```

Answer (score 3):

Typically with JMS you would define the `QueueConnectionFactory` in your container via whatever configuration mechanism it makes available then add it to the container's JNDI registry. Each container would have it's own methods for doing that (i.e. Tomcat versus WebSphere).

If you want to forgo JNDI, you could create an instance of [`com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/MQQueueConnectionFactory.html) directly and set the hostname, port, queueManager, and channel properties on it. You can then use that object as you would an instance of `javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory` since it implements it.

Answer (score 2):

I can't teach you JMS in a single post, but I can point you to some of the resources that I used to learn it myself:

1. The O'Reilly [Java Message Service](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596522045) book
2. [IBM Developerworks JMS Tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jms/) (more MQSeries/Websphere MQ specific)
3. The Spring framework can help you use JMS more effectively, especially if you're developing a standalone app outside of a J2EE app server: [Spring Java Message Service documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly common. [Here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/1_3_1-fcs/doc/client.html#1056518) are some examples.

Comment: Thnaks. How can i put (hostname, channel, port, queueManager) into the connection obj?

Comment: @David: You can't.  JMS requires you to use JNDI for that.

Comment: @Cosmic.osmo - See the other responses for examples of how to set properties of the CF object without JNDI.  JMS leaves it up to the transport provider to specify exactly what properties to set and the values to use.  The JMS spec prohibit this nor does it enforce in any way that this must be done via JNDI.